CORS Issue in Kotlin Multiplatform Project Using Server with Ktor
I have a demo project where I'm testing various architectural approaches, patterns, and technologies for Android. Currently, I am working on the server side using Kotlin Multiplatform and have encountered a technical issue that I cannot resolve myself. Here's the task: I have a Ktor server that returns a list of objects upon request:
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0", module = Application::module)
        .start(wait = true)
}

fun Application.module() {
    routing {
        get("/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/forks") {
            call.respondText(forksJson(), ContentType.Application.Json, HttpStatusCode.OK)
        }
    }
}

And a client - a website that also uses Ktor to send requests to the server to retrieve a list of objects:
HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
            ignoreUnknownKeys = true
        })
    }
}

I run the server and the web application on the same laptop (macOS). When trying to execute the request, I receive the following error:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/forks' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I tried different solutions, such as setting up CORS on the server:
install(CORS) {
    allowMethod(HttpMethod.Options)
    allowMethod(HttpMethod.Get)
    allowMethod(HttpMethod.Post)
    allowHeader(HttpHeaders.XForwardedProto)
    allowHeader(HttpHeaders.Authorization)
    allowHeader(HttpHeaders.ContentType)
    allowCredentials = true
    anyHost() 
}

And settings on the client side:
httpClient.get("${baseUrl}repos/octocat/Spoon-Knife/forks") {
    headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080")
    headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
}

Unfortunately, nothing has worked to achieve the desired result. I would be grateful for any help.

No Access-Control-* header should be set on the client side; those are response headers.

I added Access-Control-* while searching for a fix for the CORS issue. There is a possibility of incorrect use. Therefore, I am forced to turn to the community for help. So that they tell me how to implement it so that it works without errors.

While setting up CORS in the server you have forgot to add one header, which is causing you the issue.If you add the header for access control allow origin, it should work fine. You can add it like this:
allowHeader(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin)


Thanks for the tip. Added allowHeader(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin) to server`s header.
But unfortunately I get the same error.

I found that this error occurs if you run a server on a localhost and a web on the same localhost. But I couldn`t find how to fix.
Or this is a feature of development on the multiplatform side. Then it would be good to look at a successful case of implementing a server + web in a multi-platform project

I wrote the server creation code from scratch and added Cors rules by adding allowHeader(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin) to it. And everything worked for me.
Maybe there were conflicting headers somewhere or some other extra code.
Final view of the working Cors: install(CORS) {
anyHost()
allowHeader(HttpHeaders.ContentType)
allowHeader(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin)
}

After checking all optios and few hours later :) I found this solution when host and server are on localhost. The allowSameOrigin did the trick.
    install(CORS) {
        anyHost()
        allowHeader(HttpHeaders.ContentType)
        allowHeader(HttpHeaders.AccessControlAllowOrigin)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Delete)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Get)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Put)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Post)
        allowMethod(HttpMethod.Options)
        allowSameOrigin
    }ere

